# DevDays 2009 video recorded

Tags: discussion, status-completed, devdays, devdays-2009, videos

Will there be a video recording of DevDays 2009? Is that planned? Is anyone planning to do it for the rest of us that can not go and would really like to see what was happening there? :)

Comment: This looks like a good idea, although they might want to sell it, I'm cool with that. They should make it available.

Comment: Yes, I'm totally OK with it to pay for it. As long as it is available.

Comment: I would defiantly pay money for the videos.

Comment: I'm OK with charging other people for it *as long as the attendees get a copy free.*

Comment: I think it would be silly to sell it, personally. Toss it up on blip.tv or see if Google will give you a bit fancy account on youtube and host all of the videos there.

Comment: I think the problem with posting it on the web will be the length.  There are 8 different events all with different speakers.  If you figure there are 6 hours of content per event, that's almost 50 hours of viewing.

Comment: @Kevin Google Video hosts long videos, it could be 6 videos per event. But I'm not sure if it is possible to upload to Google Video anymore. Also Google allows hosting long videos on YouTube, if Google "like you" or something :) There IS a way to do this for sure.

Comment: I must have them!!!

Comment: First thing that came to mind is that we'll have a proof that Jon Skeet is not just some advanced S[OFU] responding bot.

Comment: So, are you recording them?

Answer (score 9):

That would be nice to have them recorded.  If you decide to do them again, could you put one in say Chicago, for us people who are too lame to live in Europe or on one of the coasts?

So it sounds like Joel doesn't like Chicago, so Indianapolis, Louisville, Dayton, or Cincinnati would work for me also.

Comment: Or Minneapolis, or Des Moines!!!

Comment: Or Phoenix      !

Answer (score 9):

Jon Skeet's London talk was semi-professionally video recorded here:

http://carsonified.com/blog/dev/jon-skeet-at-stack-overflow-dev-days-london/

Alex Rozanski was kind enough to video record my Cambridge talk here, and it came out pretty good:

http://www.vimeo.com/7355062

Not sure if there's anything else official

Answer (score 6):

If they are recorded, and if they are made freely available, just stating my preference for blip.tv over youtube as the host.  Blip.tv make it easy to download the video files in whatever format you need.  Makes it much more efficient to watch in two or more sittings or on the TV instead of in front of the computer.

(Yes, I know there are tools to enable downloading from YT, but you usually end up with poorer quality and it's a fiddle.)

Answer (score 5):

Given the absence of an official answer, it might be prudent to try and see if we can organize unofficial recordings of the event. Does anyone going to DevDays have a video camera? If you do and you're willing to record a talk or two at your city, post the details in this thread.

Comment: I'm going to the one in Boston and I have a digital camera with video-recording capabilities. It isn't the best, but I'll at least be able to get one or two of the panels. Should we all claim spots? :-P

Comment: @Pandincus: How long can your camera record? I have a simple digital camera that's 4 years old that takes video, but I can't get more than a few minutes out of it.

Comment: I tried taking video in Austin but there was no good spot to place my recorder and I absolutely **hate** inconveniencing the people behind me with the distracting glow of the recorder.  However, I did take audio of the event and am planning on putting it on my blog in the next day or so (I wanted to be sure people were interested first).

Comment: See my post below

Answer (score 3):

I know the audio from San Francisco (which is pretty similar) was put in last week's podcast, but I recorded Jeff's talk at Cambridge yesterday (with video) and [uploaded it](http://vimeo.com/7355062).

Audio came out pretty well and there's some questions at the end that he took and answered from the audience.