# Will presentation recordings from DevDays be available?

Tags: feature-request, devdays, devdays-2009, audio

Living on a remote island in the south Pacific, I couldn't justify the overseas travel to attend any of the DevDays presentations. However the [reports](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24994/can-someone-write-a-review-of-the-so-devdays/25003#25003) from the Boston event sound like there were some really good talks.

I'd like to be able to listen to the presentations; this would be a great addition to the current Stack Overflow podcast content (which, of course, is already a bit lighter during DevDays). Many other conferences make audio available through [IT Conversations](http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org).

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7350/devdays-video-recorded

Answer (score 11):

I asked Joel about this, and IIRC (I can't find the email) he said that he hoped so, but it would depend on what was available.

Personally I really hope they *are* recorded - and I don't think it particularly screws over people who've gone any more than people who attend live concerts are screwed over by videos coming out. Actually "being there" is part of the value.

Comment: They will just sell the DVD for $99 ;-) with a opening discount off course!

Answer (score 5):

From the perspective of a speaker, I hope the talks are recorded. I'm going to spend quite a while researching, writing and practising my talk. I would like as many people as possible to benefit from this.

It's very exciting to see how many people are actually interested in a talk you give. I gave my last talk four times, to a total in-the-flesh audience of about 140 people, but nearly 8000 people (to date!) have watched it online. That's quite an economy of scale.

Answer (score 0):

I would like this as well, but I won't be holding my breath. This would kind of screw the people who paid to go out of the entry cost.

Comment: It would benefit everybody, because I doubt anybody has paid to attend *all* the DevDays events, and they each have a different set of speakers.

Comment: If the only value you get from going to a conference is watching the talks, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Given how cheep DevDays are, I don't see this as a problem.

Comment: @Ian: "cheep"? WTF