# Will there be DevDays in 2010?

Tags: discussion, devdays

I'm a sad that I missed DevDays in London this year.
Are there any plans for 2010?

London would be fine, otherwise I recommend Munich:-)

Comment: Misread this question as "Will there be DevDays in 2012?"

Comment: @Andrew: what about 2013?

Comment: No, is bad luck ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's fairly certain there will be more DevDays in <s>2010</s> 2011, though details are completely up in the air at this point.

edit: Joel responded with a blog entry https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/devdays/

Comment: *"completely up in the air"* ooooh, devdays on airplanes!

Comment: DevDays will return, but not until 2011, see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/devdays/

Comment: Finally DevDays return, woohooo: http://devdays.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0):

Registration for DevDays 2011 is up: http://devdays.stackoverflow.com/