# What is the exact precondition to be able to get/buy/find Stack overflow T-shirt-s?

Tags: discussion, t-shirt

I saw some questions here about them. How can I get one? I did not find any webshop where they are distributed.

**Edit:** I did not ask about the store **I asked about how can I get the T-shirts?**

Comment: The online store has closed. I do not think that they are available anymore, except on special promotional occasions where they are sent to qualifying users.

Comment: I know you didn't ask about the store. You cannot get one. You *may* be given one, but that is entirely up to the discretion of Stack Exchange staff, there are no 'rules' you can follow. A T-Shirt is **not** a badge.

Comment: If you're serious about it, some of the veteran developers got such a shirt. For example [Jarrod](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27687/what-would-you-change-about-devdays-next-year/27807#comment58596_27807), so you can suggest him in private (see his profile for contact info) to buy the shirt from him, if he still got it. Of course he might ignore or refuse, but won't hurt to try. :)

Comment: So you'll just get one if you have luck and some unknown condition is met.

Comment: https://twitter.com/tinkertim/status/367588713506697216