# Are there any videos of the DevDays 2009 tutorials available anywhere?

Tags: discussion, devdays, devdays-2009, videos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DevDays 2009 video recorded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7350/devdays-2009-video-recorded)

In [What topics would you like to learn at DevDays 2011?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88052/what-topics-would-you-like-to-learn-at-devdays-2011) Joel mentioned a number of interesting topics that were presented at the 2009 conferences.

> Two years ago, the topics we tried to cover were jQuery, Python, iPhone development, ASP.NET MVC, Google App Engine, etc.

Were these recorded?  Are any of them available for download?  I'm most interested in jQuery, Python, and Google App Engine if anyone knows where to find them, but I'm sure others will be interested in any of the tutorials that are available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Jeff's answer on this [original post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7350/devdays-video-recorded).

[Jon Skeet's London talk](http://carsonified.com/blog/dev/jon-skeet-at-stack-overflow-dev-days-london/) was semi-professionally video recorded.

Alex Rozanski was kind enough to video record Jeff Atwood's [Cambridge talk](http://www.vimeo.com/7355062).

Comment: Thanks for finding that.  I did search, but I just got a bunch of "DevDays 2009 Reviews" results.  :)

Comment: @Bill, yeah, it didn't have 2009 in the title or text since it was the first one, but I edited it in for future searchers.